# Treasure maps not helping

Tags: divinity-original-sin

I purchased the maps and they show me where the X is on my map but when I go there I cannot dug up a mound because it doesn't show any mounds to dig. I have 4 maps that show where to go but nothing there to dig, do I need higher perception with my players?

Answer (score 4):

You basically have two options:

1. Improve the perception of your character(s) until the mound appears. For treasures, it's a higher threshold than other spots you can dig at.
2. Just perform the dig where you think the treasure is, if you're in the right spot, the chest should just pop out. The maps give you a pretty good idea of where it is, so you can just perform the shovel action in the area you believe it is in.

   2a. If you don't care, you can always look up the exact locations of all the treasures to dig in the right spot. (Google the map and you'll find pictures, videos, etc on how to/where to get the treasures)

I typically guessed with shoveling until the treasure showed up. On occasion, my perception was high enough to reveal the location.

**You need high wits to raise it. You can temporarily raise wits with 'Peace of Mind' (skill or scroll).**
Here's [a thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/DivinityOriginalSin/comments/3r3cu0/perception_for_treasures/) that discusses the same approach.

Note that some treasures aren't chests such as

> [the ruby under a dirt pile](https://steamcommunity.com/app/435150/discussions/3/1730963192548405675/).

Comment: "You can always look up the exact locations" how?

Comment: Google, look at a video, look at a picture, it'd be meta-gaming/cheating but it's technically an option.

Comment: My point was that it wasn't clear from your post. Thanks for the edit.

Comment: I watched a guy do it on youtube but when I go to the exact spots and use my shovel my guy said All this digging and nothing to show for it. I'm at level 9 but the highest perception in my group is 8.

Comment: You may have to dig a bunch around the supposed location. I know they're a little finicky sometimes. You may just have to get wits higher and try again. Added some more info in the answer

Comment: Thanks for the help I will keep trying and use the spell.